# Why generics reduces boxing/unboxing operations

Tags: c#, .net, generics

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5bx6xee.aspx)

```
// The .NET Framework 2.0 way to create a list
List<int> list1 = new List<int>();

// No boxing, no casting:
list1.Add(3);
```

I understand there is no casting. But why no [boxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) happens?

"3" is on stack and list is in heap.

How it happens that value from stack moved to heap without boxing?

What happens under the hood?

Comment: I don't understand the last example, why is trying to pass a string in to a int parameter surprising that is causes a compile time error? Also could you also edit in your definition of "boxing"? I don't doubt you know it, but many people don't or get it wrong and it would be good to clear that up. **EDIT:** I see, the example you took it from was comparing `List<T>` to an `ArrayList` where that last call would have worked.

Comment: Sorry - removed unnecessary code from snippet.
The question is about boxing/unboxing operations.

Comment: Don't think of boxing as 'moving a value type to the heap'.  Rather, it's creating a new object (a box) and copying the value into the box.  You can then pass around the reference to that box.  This was handy prior to generics when collections could only contain references.  Since they can now store value types directly, there is no need to put them in boxes first.  The fact that the backing array storage for the list lives on the heap is immaterial.

Comment: Your fundamental misunderstanding is thinking that value types have anything to do with the stack or the heap. What determines whether a variable is on the stack or heap is **how long it lives**, not whether it is a value type or reference type. When you make a class with a field of type int, an instance of that class puts an int on the heap, right?  That's not a contradiction; the field lives for longer than the lifetime of the method, so it goes on the heap.

Comment: No boxing happens because boxing is the conversion of a value type to a reference type. No conversion happens here, so no boxing.

Answer (score 3):

Boxing doesn't happen here because the array that backs the List is `T[]`, not `object[]`. Therefore, the runtime knows your items are integers and doesn't need to box them.

Comment: Hm... This way we'll have int[] as a field of List<T>.
But what happens if i do the following?
list[0]++;
Will the value be taken from heap copied to stack, increased and then copied back to heap?

Comment: @vitaliy, if it has registers free, the jitter may decide not to use the stack at all.  Value types don't have to always be on the stack.

Comment: @Vitaliy, also, it's worth noting that '++' is implicitly calling a getter and setter here on the list.  Don't take this to mean that you can create a list of value types with a method `MutateMe` and say `list[0].MutateMe()`; because the result is not being saved back to the list, you're mutating a copy of the value, not the actual contents of the list.

Comment: @DanBryant That's not true.  `++` does actually mutate the *variable* not the *value in that variable*.  When you call it on a array of ints you do actually mutate the value in the array.

Comment: @Servy, when you call it on an array, yes, but this is a list.  Wouldn't it call get_Item, increment and then call set_Item?

Comment: @DanBryant yes it does: callvirt get_Item(), add, callvirt set_Item

Answer (score 0):

List already has a preallocated array of ints on the heap so it only needs to change one of those ints to 3.